# AURenderCallback.inputProc triggering in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios-simulator, ipod-touch, audio-recording

In this case both the device is an iPod running iOS4.2 and the simulator is 4.2 as well.

the setup code is taken(exactly) from the 'aurioTouch' example.  Running thru the debugger shows that all gets setup properly.   I'm posting an NSLog message from the callback, which gets posted to the console from the simulator but not from the device.  It is simply not getting triggered on the device.  :-(

The Property Listener callback gets called (and properly runs) when a mic is plugged in as well as removed.

The Interruption Listener gets called as well.

Anyone have any clues why this may happen?  I've already done a few google searches and cant track anything on my own yet :-S

thanks in advance

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer at least to my case.  Remove any any changes to the AudioSession such as the prefferedHardwareIOBufferDuration and test the app again.